# Limit ticks on X axis in highcharts with R

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, axis

I'm trying get a proper date X axis on my highcharts graph I created in R. When I use the variable as `Date` `highcharts` doesn't seem to understand it and when I convert to characters all X labels are shown, which doesn't look nice. With the NVD3 graph from the rCharts package there is the option `reduceXticks=TRUE` which would solve this. Maybe there is an equivalent?

Example:

```
# data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100), s = 100*rnorm(100), z = 10*rnorm(100),Date=
                   as.POSIXct(seq(Sys.Date(), by = 1, length.out = 100)))

# chart 1
h1 <- Highcharts$new()

h1$xAxis(categories=df$Date,type = "datetime")
h1$yAxis(list(list(title = list(text = 'x'), opposite = FALSE), 
              list(title = list(text = 'y'), opposite = TRUE),
              list(title = list(text = 's'), opposite = TRUE)))
h1$series(name = 'x', type = 'line', color = '#000099',
          data = df$x)
h1$series(name = 'y', type = 'line', color = '#FF0000',
          data = df$y, yAxis=1)
h1$series(name = 's', type = 'line', color = '#006600',
          data = df$s, yAxis=2)
h1
#-------------------------------------------------------------#

h1 <- Highcharts$new()

h1$xAxis(categories=as.character(df$Date),type = "datetime")
h1$yAxis(list(list(title = list(text = 'x'), opposite = FALSE), 
              list(title = list(text = 'y'), opposite = TRUE),
              list(title = list(text = 's'), opposite = TRUE)))
h1$series(name = 'x', type = 'line', color = '#000099',
          data = df$x)
h1$series(name = 'y', type = 'line', color = '#FF0000',
          data = df$y, yAxis=1)
h1$series(name = 's', type = 'line', color = '#006600',
          data = df$s, yAxis=2)
h1
```

[image: Image 1][image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `minTickInterval` option for `xAxis`

> ```
> minTickInterval: NumberSince
> ```
>
> The minimum tick interval allowed in axis values. For example on
>   zooming in on an axis with daily data, this can be used to prevent the
>   axis from showing hours. Defaults to the closest distance between two
>   points on the axis.

From http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minTickInterval.

Alternatively, set a custom number of ticks using `tickInterval`:

> ```
> tickInterval: Number
> ```
>
> The interval of the tick marks in axis units. When null, the tick
>   interval is computed to approximately follow the tickPixelInterval on
>   linear and datetime axes. On categorized axes, a null tickInterval
>   will default to 1, one category. **Note that datetime axes are based
>   on milliseconds, so for example an interval of one day is expressed as
>   24 * 3600 * 1000**.

From http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval.

Hence, in your case, perhaps you should use weekly ticks, i.e., `tickInterval = 7* 24 * 3600 * 1000`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the new package `highcharter` which include some shortcuts functions to create chart (using highstock too) given date and values. Check the link http://jkunst.com/highcharter/oldindex.html#time-series

[image]

Comment: This looks great at first sight! Thanks for creating this package.

Comment: At second sight the examples look not great but awesome! Would it also be possible to add points: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-click-to-add this is something I was struggling with for many hours in rCharts....

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht It's possible. You need to transform the js object to highcharter syntax: `hc_chart(type = "scatter", margins = c(70, 50, 60, 80))), ...`) in the events case you need a function you need pass the function as text adding the `JS` function: `events = list(click = JS("function(e){ .... }"))`. If you have more doubts we can discuss in the github repository. Regards,